# How to deploy page layout in Salesforce managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, page-layout

I have added a custom object related to contact and added that related list section together with a custom button into Contact layout. I created the managed package and put the Contact layout into the package. However, after deployment into the test org, I still don't see the related list there. It's not added into the page layout.

Since we are planning to publish this package into App Exchange so we need to resolve it. By searching in internet, it seems to be a known issue in Salesforce. However, is there any walk around for it? Putting a button in the VF setup page is quite acceptable in this case.

Comment: did you added the custom button to package as well. bcz it has layout will have dependency with custom button.

Comment: Did you do a fresh install, or an upgrade? Page layouts are not upgrade-able.

Comment: @sfdcfox I did an update. It is a bit weird we can't add new things to the existing page layout